# Bind members of different classes

Tags: c++

In a C++ program I have two classes (structs) like

```
struct A
{
    int x;
    double y;
    // other members
};

struct B
{
    int x;
    double y2;
    // other members
};
```

I'd like to somehow "bind" the corresponding members, e.g. `A::x` to `B::x` and `A::y` to `B::y2`. By "bind" I mean ability to obtain a reference to the bound variable, for example given a member of class `A` I could assign it to the value of the corresponding `B` member.

Once I have such bind, I'd like to build a *bind table* or something similar which I could iterate over. This would allow, for example, copying the corresponding fields from `A a;` to `B b;` like `CopyBound(a, b, bind_table);`, but probably also doing some other things not limited to `Copy` interface.

The problem with this bind_table is that I want static typing and the bind_table would have to contain different types in this case. For example, a table of pointers to class members would contain `&A::x` and `&A::y`, but they are of different type, so I cannot just put them say into an array.

Any ideas how this can be conveniently implemented, having as much compile-time type checking as possible?

Comment: Please clarify if this is C or C++ at least.

Comment: @Jon: I'm talking about C++, but probably some C-style solution could go as well

Comment: Your question is unclear. The binding part is easy (if you mean what I think you mean), but it's not clear what you want the "bind table" to be or do. Copying fields frm `A a` to `B b`? If `a` and `b` are already bound then copying is unnecessary, and if they aren't then it has nothing to do with the binding.

Comment: @Beta: sorry I don't know how to make it more clear... in my definition, when `A::x` is "bound" to `B::x` it does not mean they are the same, it just means they (not their values!) are related, so I would still need to copy their values say from `A` to `B`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want some template metaprogramming along the lines of this:

```
#include <iostream>

// An item in the list of bound members
template<typename Class, typename T, T Class::*Ptr, typename Next = void> struct m
{
    typedef Class containing_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef Next next;
    static T Class::*pointer;
};
template<typename Class, typename T, T Class::*Ptr, typename Next>
    T Class::* m<Class, T, Ptr, Next>::pointer = Ptr;

// Iterator for the member list
template<typename Item1, typename Item2> struct apply_helper
{
    typedef typename Item1::containing_type A;
    typedef typename Item2::containing_type B;

    template<typename Op>
    static void apply(A& a, B& b, Op op)
    {
        op(a.*Item1::pointer, b.*Item2::pointer);
        apply_helper<typename Item1::next, typename Item2::next>::apply(a, b, op);
    }
};

template<typename Item1> struct apply_helper<Item1, void>
{
    // An error referencing this means you forgot a member in the list
};
template<typename Item2> struct apply_helper<void, Item2>
{
    // An error referencing this means you forgot a member in the list
};
template<> struct apply_helper<void, void>
{
        template<typename A, typename B, typename Op>
        static void apply(A& a, B& b, Op op) {}
};


// This function initiates the enumeration of the members
template<typename A, typename B, typename Op> void apply(A& a, B& b, Op op)
{
    apply_helper<typename A::members, typename B::members>::apply(a, b, op);
}


// EXAMPLE

struct MyA
{
    int v1;
    double v2;
    typedef m<MyA, int, &MyA::v1,
            m<MyA, double, &MyA::v2> > members;
};

struct MyB
{
    int v1;
    double v2;
    typedef m<MyB, int, &MyB::v1,
            m<MyB, double, &MyB::v2> > members;
};

// A functor which demonstrates printing the value before copying    
struct CopyAnyValue
{
    template<typename T> void operator()(T& t1, T& t2)
    {
        std::cout << "t1 = " << t1 << std::endl;
        t2 = t1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyA a;
    MyB b;

    a.v1 = 3;
    a.v2 = 5.5;

    apply(a, b, CopyAnyValue());

    std::cout << "v1: " << b.v1 << "  v2: " << b.v2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```